# Match Against and left join shows error

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search, mysql-error-1064

So I have two tables like this, first table (*) and second table (*)

*

So, it's possible to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `FROM` table list and `JOINs` must come before the `WHERE` clause of the query.

I don't know if the rest of the query was right, but this is it in the right order:

```
SELECT id_maestro, nombre, materia 
FROM maestros_detalle AS t1 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, up, down FROM maestros) AS t2 ON t1.id_maestro = t2.id 
WHERE MATCH (t1.nombre, t1.materia) 
AGAINST ('quimica' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY t1.id_maestro
```

Cleaned up:

```
SELECT
  t1.id_maestro,
  t1.nombre,
  t1.materia,
  t2.up,
  t2.down
FROM
  maestros_detalle t1
LEFT JOIN
  maestros t2
ON 
  t1.id_maestro = t2.id
WHERE
  MATCH(t1.nombre, t1.materia) AGAINST ('quimica' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY
  t1.id_maestro
```

Comment: That query works now, but it only shows id_maestro, nombre, materia, where did my 'up' and 'down' go?

Comment: You didn't select up or down. Add t2.up, t2.down to your `SELECT` list. I don't understand the reason for the subquery actually, I'm going to edit my post to show without that.

Comment: Oh thank you, that query now works perfectly, now I'm gonna try to understand it.